# Data source not created for sound on ubuntu - JMF

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmf

I am creating a movie file using images and sound file. Using images the movie file is created without any problem but when I merge the sound file it  throws following exception

> javax.media.NoDataSourceException: Error instantiating class:
>   com.sun.media.protocol.http.DataSource : java.awt.AWTError: Could not
>   instantiate Toolkit: sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit  at
>   javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(Manager.java:1017)   at
>   javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(Manager.java:931)

I am using Manager class to create data source of sound URL. The exception throws on following line. This works on my windows machine without any problem. But it is not working on our ubuntu server.

```
DataSource ds = Manager.createDataSource(soundURL);
```

Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: what is the soundURL value?

Comment: It is just a location of a file. Like "D:\Audio\abc.au".